# Remove all special characters from string in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all special characters from string and add only one "-"(hyphen) in the place.

Consider below example

```
var string = 'Lorem%^$&*&^Ipsum#^is@!^&simply!dummy text.'
```

So, from the above string, if there is a continuous number of special characters then I want to remove all of them and add only one "-" or if there is a single or double special character then also that should be replaced by "-"

Result should be like this

```
Lorem-Ipsum-is-simply-dummy text-
```

I have tried below, but no luck

```
var newString = sourceString.replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-");
```

Comment: added tried code

Comment: . also should get removed, and _ as well

Comment: so sorry for that, i have changed the question.

Comment: do you want leading/trailing `-` kept or removed?

Comment: why u downvote to this question?

Comment: who is `u`? and why do you care? You still haven't figured out your *expected output* ... above includes space, below you say you don't want space ... you also don't show any attempt (somebody removed it perhaps?)

Comment: Krishna Prashitt removed your attempt when making minor (very unnecessary) changes to your question - blame Krishna for the downvotes because it now looks like you didn't try at all!!

Comment: i already shown the expected result above dude, also i shown the code which i have tried

Comment: yeah? so spaces and `.` pass through?

Comment: i agreed with my mistake on "." but if someone changed my question, its not my fault

Comment: but they didn't change the *expected output*

Comment: ok. sorry for this. i will keep this in mind for next time. Thanks

Comment: I know it's not your fault ... SO is a harsh place at the best of times .. doubly so when some random low rep numbnut edits your question!!

Comment: i will keep this in mind next time for sure, and BTW Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.replace` to replace all non-alphabetical character substrings with `-`:

```js
const input = 'Lorem%^$&*&^Ipsum#^is@!^&simply!dummy text.';
const output = input.replace(/[^\w\s]+/gi, '-');
console.log(output);
```

If you want to permit numbers too:

```js
const input = 'Lorem123%^$&*&^654Ipsum#^is@!^&simply!dummy text.';
const output = input.replace(/[^\w\s\d]+/gi, '-');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `/[^a-z0-9]+/gi` ?

Comment: could you help me to remove the . as well. i will be thankfull

Comment: what do you mean? it does do that!

Comment: @AmolRokade It's already removed from the string..? `I want to remove all special characters from string and add only one "-" in the place.`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - you need to add `\s` to **allow** space :p

Comment: "output is `Lorem-Ipsum-is-simply-dummy text`" - *yes you do*

Comment: @AmolRokade Your desired output includes the space. I highly recommend trying to figure out what you want the output to be like *before* posting a question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Your answer is correct. Its working fine for me